# Schunk LWA4P initialization problem with ros_canopen

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I try to launch a LW4P with ros_canopen. I use ROS kinetic and a PCAN-USB Pro adapter.
I already tried out the suggestions on similar problems on [ROS answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/289428/schunk_lwa4d-problem-initialising-with-ros_canopen/) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_robots/issues/59) but unfortunately my issue remains.

First I setup my CAN interface

```
$ ~/catkin-pem-robot-v2# sudo ip link set can0 down
$ ~/catkin-pem-robot-v2# sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
$ ~/catkin-pem-robot-v2# sudo ip link set can0 up txqueuelen 20
```

Then I launch the robot

```
$ ~/catkin-pem-robot-v2$ roslaunch pem_robot pem_robot_v3.launch 
WARNING: Could not change permissions for folder [/home/verena/.ros/log/c8077c0a-8dbd-11e9-b028-ac7ba18b123a], make sure that the parent folder has correct permissions.
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://verena-CELSIUS-H730:33227/

SUMMARY
========

CLEAR PARAMETERS
 * /lh_arm/driver/

PARAMETERS
 * /joint_state_mixer/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /lh_arm/driver/bus/device: can0
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/604Csub1: 1
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/604Csub2: 24000
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/6060: 1
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/eds_file: config/Schunk_0_6...
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/eds_pkg: pem_arm_lh
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/vel_to_device: rint(rad2deg(vel)...
 * /lh_arm/driver/name: arm
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_0_joint/id: 10
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_1_joint/id: 5
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_2_joint/id: 6
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_3_joint/id: 3
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_4_joint/id: 4
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_5_joint/id: 7
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_6_joint/id: 8
 * /lh_arm/driver/sync/interval_ms: 50
 * /lh_arm/driver/sync/overflow: 0
 * /lh_arm/hardware_control_loop/loop_hz: 125
 * /lh_arm/hardware_interface/joints: ['lh_arm_0_joint'...
 * /lh_arm/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /lh_arm/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/joints: ['lh_arm_0_joint'...
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/publish_rate: 50
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/required_drive_mode: 7
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/type: position_controll...
 * /lh_arm/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /lh_arm/
    driver (canopen_motor_node/canopen_motor_node)
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    robot_initialization (rosservice/rosservice)
    ros_control_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
  /
    joint_state_mixer (pem_robot/joint_state_mixer.py)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [6027]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to c8077c0a-8dbd-11e9-b028-ac7ba18b123a
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6052]
started core service [/rosout]
process[lh_arm/driver-2]: started with pid [6071]
process[lh_arm/ros_control_controller_spawner-3]: started with pid [6072]
process[lh_arm/joint_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [6073]
process[lh_arm/robot_initialization-5]: started with pid [6074]
process[joint_state_mixer-6]: started with pid [6083]
process[robot_state_publisher-7]: started with pid [6093]
[ INFO] [1560418188.416560376]: Using fixed control period: 0.050000000
[INFO] [1560418188.461155]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ INFO] [1560418188.509712642]: Initializing XXX
[ INFO] [1560418188.510056097]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1560418188.510289199]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
EMCY: 8A#2232257400000000
EMCY: 85#223225740000803F
EMCY: 86#2232257400001C42
[ INFO] [1560418199.018367789]: Current state: 2 device error: system:125 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1560418199.018453747]: Current state: 0 device error: system:125 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1560418199.018552617]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1560418199.018681225]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[lh_arm/robot_initialization-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/verena/.ros/log/c8077c0a-8dbd-11e9-b028-ac7ba18b123a/lh_arm-robot_initialization-5*.log
[WARN] [1560418218.726126]: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
[lh_arm/ros_control_controller_spawner-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/verena/.ros/log/c8077c0a-8dbd-11e9-b028-ac7ba18b123a/lh_arm-ros_control_controller_spawner-3*.log
```

This is my candump: https://justpaste.it/1rgt9

---

EDIT:

Thanks to Mathias Lüdtke power supply was one issue.
Now I get the following output:

```
$ roslaunch pem_robot pem_robot_v3.launch 
WARNING: Could not change permissions for folder [/home/verena/.ros/log/74e55cd4-9689-11e9-a9ae-f54b2e588d05], make sure that the parent folder has correct permissions.
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://verena-CELSIUS-H730:37665/

SUMMARY
========

CLEAR PARAMETERS
 * /lh_arm/driver/

PARAMETERS
 * /joint_state_mixer/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /lh_arm/driver/bus/device: can0
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/604Csub1: 1
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/604Csub2: 24000
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/dcf_overlay/6060: 1
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/eds_file: config/Schunk_0_6...
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/eds_pkg: pem_arm_lh
 * /lh_arm/driver/defaults/vel_to_device: rint(rad2deg(vel)...
 * /lh_arm/driver/name: arm
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_0_joint/id: 10
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_1_joint/id: 5
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_2_joint/id: 6
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_3_joint/id: 3
 * /lh_arm/driver/nodes/lh_arm_4_joint/id: 4
 * /lh_arm/driver/sync/interval_ms: 50
 * /lh_arm/driver/sync/overflow: 0
 * /lh_arm/hardware_control_loop/loop_hz: 125
 * /lh_arm/hardware_interface/joints: ['lh_arm_0_joint'...
 * /lh_arm/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /lh_arm/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/joints: ['lh_arm_0_joint'...
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/publish_rate: 50
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/required_drive_mode: 7
 * /lh_arm/pos_based_pos_traj_controller_arm_lh/type: position_controll...
 * /lh_arm/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /lh_arm/
    driver (canopen_motor_node/canopen_motor_node)
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    robot_initialization (rosservice/rosservice)
    ros_control_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
  /
    joint_state_mixer (pem_robot/joint_state_mixer.py)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [18482]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 74e55cd4-9689-11e9-a9ae-f54b2e588d05
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [18508]
started core service [/rosout]
process[lh_arm/driver-2]: started with pid [18526]
process[lh_arm/ros_control_controller_spawner-3]: started with pid [18527]
process[lh_arm/joint_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [18528]
process[lh_arm/robot_initialization-5]: started with pid [18529]
process[joint_state_mixer-6]: started with pid [18537]
process[robot_state_publisher-7]: started with pid [18548]
[ INFO] [1561385275.960165419]: Using fixed control period: 0.050000000
[ INFO] [1561385275.968221068]: Initializing XXX
[ INFO] [1561385275.968553515]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1561385275.968718042]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[INFO] [1561385275.993059]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ INFO] [1561385286.459056976]: Current state: 2 device error: system:125 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1561385286.459180627]: Current state: 0 device error: system:125 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1561385286.459249766]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[ INFO] [1561385286.459341893]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
[lh_arm/robot_initialization-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/verena/.ros/log/74e55cd4-9689-11e9-a9ae-f54b2e588d05/lh_arm-robot_initialization-5*.log
```

I am still not able to launch the LWA4P and I encountered some strange things:
It seems that some of my CAN modules are not recognized at all. At the startup `candump can0` only gives me the following:

```
can0 705 [1] 00 
can0 706 [1] 00 
can0 70A [1] 00
```

If I only launch the recognized nodes without the non-recognized nodes, I can move the recognized nodes as expected.
I also double-checked my CAN module IDs and CANopen communication mode with the Schunk Motion tool.

What could be the reason for not recognizing some of my modules?

Thank you in advance!
Any help is highly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325633/schunk-lwa4p-initialization-problem-with-ros_canopen/) by [verena](https://answers.ros.org/users/37639/verena/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adrienH](https://answers.ros.org/users/28141/adrienh/) on 2019-06-20**:
Hello , did you try to start just the driver "canopen_motor_node"  and manualy spawn your controller ? with rqt if it's easyer.

Is your candump complete ? I don't see node many node state in you candump but, as log indicates a controller interface not found probleme.

I think it migh help if you send your configuration file *controller.yaml and canopen_chaine_node.yaml etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
EMCY: 8A#2232257400000000
EMCY: 85#223225740000803F
EMCY: 86#2232257400001C42
```

If I am  not mistaken, this is an under-voltage emergency alert (`0x3222`).
Please check your power supply.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [verena](https://answers.ros.org/users/37639/verena/) on 2019-06-24**:
thank you! Yes apparently power supply was one issue. The EMCY message have disappeared now. However, the other error messages are remaining and I am still not able to launch the LWA4P.
I encountered some strange things:
It seems that some of my CAN modules are not recognized at all. At the startup `candump can0` only gives me the following
 `can0  705   [1]  00 can0  706   [1]  00 can0  70A   [1]  00`
If I only launch the recognized nodes without the non-recognized nodes, I can move the recognized nodes as expected.

But what could be the reason for not recognizing some of my modules?

Thank you in advance!